# Printing escaped Unicode in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
>>> s = 'auszuschließen'
>>> print(s.encode('ascii', errors='xmlcharrefreplace'))
b'auszuschlie&#223;en'
>>> print(str(s.encode('ascii', errors='xmlcharrefreplace'), 'ascii'))
auszuschlie&#223;en
```

Is there a prettier way to print any string without the `b''`?

EDIT:

I'm just trying to print escaped characters from Python, and my only gripe is that Python adds "b''" when i do that.

If i wanted to see the actual character in a dumb terminal like Windows 7's, then i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Mailgen.py", line 378, in <module>
    marked_copy = mark_markup(language_column, item_row)
  File "Mailgen.py", line 210, in mark_markup
    print("TP: %r" % "".join(to_print))
  File "c:\python32\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 29: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: why aren't you just using `print(s)`? Why do you need to encode as ascii?

Comment: Because i don't think my terminal supports every weird character my code processes.

Comment: print(str(s.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'), 'ascii')) will be even prettier, anyway.

Comment: I would like to know which characters are in the string.

Comment: I've update my answer. Although that answers your question, it has the feeling of actually solving the wrong problem. The question that pops up in my mind is why you want to have a "pretty" output of what essentially is debug information (the Unicode characters in a string). Is this logging, the actual program user interface or stdout output that should be fed to another program, or...?

Comment: You could also set environment variable [PYTHONIOENCODING=cp437:backslashreplace](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) and then use `print(s)`. I didn't mentioned it in the answer because [python might crash if you set it incorrectly](http://bugs.python.org/issue6501).

Comment: I meant "prettier way" code-wise. The sys.stdout.buffer.write solution is a single function that doesn't require repetition or magic.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I had missed that  you could set error-handlers in PYTHONIOENCODING. This is IMO the correct solution.

Comment: An environment variable could affect more than it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s='auszuschließen…'
>>> s
'auszuschließen…'
>>> print(s)
auszuschließen…
>>> b=s.encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace')
>>> b
b'auszuschlie&#223;en&#8230;'
>>> print(b)
b'auszuschlie&#223;en&#8230;'
>>> b.decode()
'auszuschlie&#223;en&#8230;'
>>> print(b.decode())
auszuschlie&#223;en&#8230;
```

You start out with a Unicode string. Encoding it to `ascii` creates a `bytes` object with the characters you want. Python won't print it without converting it back into a string and the default conversion puts in the `b` and quotes. Using `decode` explicitly converts it back to a string; the default encoding is `utf-8`, and since your `bytes` only consist of `ascii` which is a subset of `utf-8` it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution so far. Note that my terminal silently turns '…' into '.'

Answer (score 4):

To see ascii representation (like `repr()` on Python 2) for debugging:

```
print(ascii('auszuschließen…'))
# -> 'auszuschlie\xdfen\u2026'
```

To print bytes:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write('auszuschließen…'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))
# -> auszuschlie&#223;en&#8230;
```

Comment: On closer inspection, in my terminal sys.stdout.buffer.write('auszuschließen…test'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')) prints: auszuschlie&#223;en.test24
I don't like special cases (uncaught return value gets printed), so i'll go with the decode() solution.

Comment: @Cees Timmerman: [no, it is not.](http://ideone.com/flXye) You might be confusing it with an interactive interpreter such as ipython, bpython, idle or just bare `python` without arguments. In this case you don't need to print the string; the interpreter echos its value by itself.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes. The point is that he wanted to print without the b''. Using ascii only prints without the b, but keeps the ''.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I meant >>> sys.stdout.buffer.write('auszuschließen.test'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefrep
lace'))
auszuschlie&#223;en.test24

Answer (score 1):

Not all terminals can handle more than some sort of 8-bit character set, that's true. But they won't handle that no matter what you do, really.

Printing a Unicode string will, assuming that your OS set's up the terminal properly, result in the best result possible, which means that the characters that the terminal can not print will be replaced with some character, like a question mark or similar. Doing that translation yourself will not really improve things.

Update:

Since you want to know what characters are in the string, you actually want to know the Unicode codes for them, or the XML equivalent in this case. That's more inspecting than printing, and then usually the b'' part isn't a problem per se.

But you can get rid of it easily and hackily like so:

```
print(repr(s.encode('ascii', errors='xmlcharrefreplace'))[2:-1])
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Mailgen.py", line 378, in <module>
    marked_copy = mark_markup(language_column, item_row)
  File "Mailgen.py", line 210, in mark_markup
    print("TP: %r" % "".join(to_print))
  File "c:\python32\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 29: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: See, there you have the start of an actual question. You should make one. Also include information about your terminal.

Comment: Okay: How do i Pythonically print an unknown Unicode string in the 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise Command terminal (and preferably any other terminal as well)?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman You should update your original question with the details that you've specified in your first comment (or ask a *new* question if it's completely different from this one); this will improve the question and give more people the opportunity to help you.

Comment: @casperOne I'm just trying to print escaped characters from Python, and my only gripe is that Python adds "b''" when i do that. This non-answer duplicates jcollado's question. Should i duplicate my answer to him in my question?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman **Stop** asking additional questions in comments.  [Update your main question with the details if it doesn't change the nature of the question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106249/update-a-question-or-post-a-new-question)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Python 3, you're afforded the ability to write `print(s)` to the console.

I can agree that, depending on the console, it may not be able to print properly, but I would imagine that most modern OSes since 2006 can handle Unicode strings without too much of an issue.  I'd encourage you to give it a try and see if it works.

Alternatively, you can enforce a coding by placing this before any lines in a *file* (similar to a shebang):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This will force the interpreter to render it as UTF-8.

Comment: This copy of 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise Command terminal, for one, does not like to print characters not in CP437, e.g. '\u2026'.

Comment: 1. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is default on Python3 2. It doesn't change how `print(s)` works. It only affects how literal strings are interpreted.